# Flagging Summary UI broken if there is no action taken or rejected

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-history

Currently

[image]

It should be like this

[image]

Comment: fair point; it shall be so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed next build (i.e. when the bottom right says something other than 2011.4.17.3)

Comment: Don't you mean .3/.4? English.SE has already been on .4 for most of today.

Comment: @waiwai933 I'm going by SO numbers ;p